# Detail Grid with DropDowns as columns dont show correct value until clicked to edit

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

Grid with Parent rows and Detail Table.
Parent row has a DropDown bound to choices.
The data in the Detail Table includes a DropDown bound to same choices.
When page 1st renders all the DropDowns in the detail table display the same choice that the parent row shows.

This is before user makes any choices. If user clicks on dropdown in detail table it will change to dropdown and show the correct choice.

How to get the detail tables to render correctly when initially displayed?